# How can I select both holes to get high density mesh?

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I'm new in Mathematica. I'm trying multiple methods to select both holes without success. Any help will be helpful. Thanks.

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 <= 1 && (x - 0.5)^2 + y^2 - 0.05 >= 
      0 && (x + 0.5)^2 + y^2 - 0.05 >= 0, {x, y}]];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> {{-0.5, 0.}}, 
 "RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.}, 0, 0.0001}}]
mesh1["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the code about bmesh.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
"RegionMarker" -> {{{0.5, 0.}, 0, 0.0001}, {{-0.5, 0.}, 1, 
 0.1}}]["Wireframe"]
```

or

```
ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionHoles" -> None]
```